# Edit rejected "intended to address author"

Tags: discussion, review-queues, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

The accepted answer to a question didn't actually contain an answer: it contained a reason for not working and an off-site link to part of the answer.

Having followed the link and solved the problem completely, I thought it preferable to update the accepted answer help people more directly rather than make them figure it out. I thought it was quite well established that vague answers whose substance is off-site are not the most desirable. **Is that not true?**

[Three reviewers rejected this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/14077887) as "intended to address the author and makes no sense as an edit". I find this to be a very strange interpretation. Clearly it expands on the existing answer to make it more complete (you could disagree for other reasons, but then why flag it with this reason?).

I don't mind adding it as an independent answer but don't really think that adds the most value.

Comment: I mean you don't know that the author wanted to say this. Edits are not meant to add a whole bunch of text to this.

Comment: This is a guess, but: I would think it's because you seemingly added content from nowhere. You mention a link in your edit summary, but there wasn't a link in the answer, and in fact the link you mention _was not posted by the answerer._ You are effectively putting words in the answerer's mouth. Now, if the answerer had posted that link, and in the answer, it would have been more likely to be accepted I would think.

Comment: I don't think it would have get accepted. If you put that much effort into improving an answer just do your own.

Comment: @Hayt If someone just links to a resource, it has been encouraged before to add a quote or to summarize the resource. I'm not saying it would _definitely_ be accepted, but it would be more likely than adding a lot of text from thin air.

Comment: @Kendra yeah it is encouraged. I personally would encourage the author more to edit the answer, than letting others to try it. If it does not happen post your own answer.

Comment: @Kendra  The linked "edit" is 4x times original post... It does not look like "summarize the resource" to me - I'd rejected that edit.

Comment: Sam, since you've already stared conversation with author of the post - they have absolute power to accept any change (or in worst case edit it in) this could be another avenue to get similar the change in.

Comment: I think the length doesn't help *in combination with other points mentioned here*, but don't think substantial length is a problem in itself. Ultimate aim is informative answers after all.

Comment: If you did this to my answer, I wouldn't consider it to be mine anymore. We could surely agree on it being ours, but there's no such thing as "an answer by me and you" on SO. So you should have your own (and get credit for it).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

> I thought it was quite well established that vague answers whose substance is off-site are not the most desirable. Is that not true?

It is.  The solution, however, is not to edit your own answer into someone else's post.  If someone else has posted a bad/problematic answer, and you have a *good* answer, you should *post your own good answer* rather than editing it into someone else's answer.

Comment: Since everyone seems to agree, I will go ahead an repost as a separate answer. I still don't really agree: the author said exactly what the edit expands on and gives examples for. They just didn't provide the exact method and examples.

Comment: @SamBrightman That's fine, you can always credit them in your answer saying they showed you where you got your answer from. Don't forget to also upvote the other person giving their answer!

Comment: @SamBrightman on the other side, the answer you tried to edit was quite generic, while your edit (and answer) provide configuration for specific environments. It is clearly more specific than what the author intended, and might not apply to all users having the same question. In fact, half of it would be an answer a follow-up question which is "_How to teach terminal emulator_ XXX _to send some special byte sequence of your choice?_"

Comment: @DidierL I disagree. The original answer briefly mentions the generic method but does not instruct how, providing an off-site link for a single terminal. My answer *both* mentions the generic method and gives *on-site* examples for the two most common terminals (including the one from the off-site link), as well as linking to a page for more niche terminals. It is more instructive for the common case, but doesn't pretend that is the only case. So the original ends up being *more* specific, but not within the answer text.

Comment: I think we're down here anyway. I would answer separately if doing this again (and have done now).

Comment: @SamBrightman The original answer does not provide any off-site link. It is only a comment, and from a different author.

Comment: Sorry, I keep conflating them in my mind.

Answer (score 10):

Edits shouldn't change the meaning of an answer. As Hayt wrote in comments:

> You don't know that the author wanted to say this.

I think you should instead post that as your own answer.

---

As a side note: if that post was a Community Wiki, it would be OK to make such an edit.

Comment: I agree it's quite a large edit for a non-community answer.

Answer (score 7):

Reading the entirety of the rejection message, the emphasis should be on:

> This edit was intended to address the author of the post and makes no sense as an edit. **It should have been written as a comment or an answer.**

Because of how extensive your "edit" was, it's much more appropriate as a completely new answer.  Additionally, you include wording like "I don't know when the former is used, perhaps single-keys only" which the author of the answer may or may not have actually said; you're putting words in their mouth and misrepresenting the scope of their answer.  Your edit was correctly rejected.  You should write a new answer.  Since it would be based on another answer, you should provide a reference to the other answer in the new answer.

Comment: Please don't imply that I didn't read properly - you could easily rephrase this as "the end of the reason is the most relevant part". As I said in this question: I am happy to post as my own answer but disagree that is the best approach here. I was not addressing the author and believe it makes sense as an edit.

Comment: @SamBrightman my apologies.  Edited

Comment: The language style is a good point, I should also have been more careful around that (if e.g. making a smaller edit).